# How to find the $l$-th root, so the inverse of $z^l:\Bbb{C}\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, inverse

We have seen the following example in class:

> Let $\Bbb{C}\stackrel{z^l}{\rightarrow } \Bbb{C}\supset B(1,1)$. I need to find $f:B(1,1)\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ such that $f(z)^l=z$. Then in class our prof splitted it into the following cases:
>
> 1. When $z\in (0,2)$ then $f(z)=z^{\frac{1}{l}}$.
> 2. for $x\in (-1,1)$ we have the taylor expansion $$(1+x)^\frac{1}{l}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{l}}{n} x^n$$which converges for $|x|<1$. Let $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{l}}{n} (z-1)^n$$ which converges absolutly for $|z-1|<1$. Then $f(z)^l=z$.

But somehow I don't get point $2$? why do we need this point I mean why can we swap from a taylor expansion for $x\in (-1,1)$ to our function, what is the idea behind this swap.

Can maybe someone explain me this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a matter of splitting into cases.

The first point relates to the real line. For any interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}^+$, it's easy to understand why there is a unique continuous function $g(x):I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $(g(x))\ ^l=x$ and $g(1)=1$. This is because the construction of the "real-valued root" is probably part of your course.

*You might wonder, what if I don't require $g(x)$ to be a real-valued function and I don't require $g(1)=1$? In the trivial case $l=1$, nevertheless $g$ would still be unique. If $l\neq\pm 1$, then $g$ is not unique. For any example $G(x)$, the complete set of examples of $g(x)$ is precisely those of the form $G(x)\exp(2\pi ik/l)$, where $k$ is any integer.*

*But let's suppose the question requires $g(x)$ to be a real-valued function and $g(x)=1$.*

Point two gives you another perspective to this question. It relies on the fact that $h(x)=(1+x)^\frac{1}{l}$ is known to be analytic on the domain $B(0,1)$ and has a Taylor series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ that converges on $B(0,1)$.

Then, by letting $z=1+x$, we see that the function $u(z)=z^\frac{1}{l}$ is analytic on $B(1,1)$ and has a Taylor series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-1)^n$ that converges on $B(1,1)$.

This $u(z)$ must be the same as the unique $g(z)$ described earlier.